# How to use WFS Request CreateStoredQuery

Tags: geoserver, wfs

I would like to [filter by WFS](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/filter/function.html#wfs-filtering).

I started with the request [CreateStoredQuery](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/reference.html#createstoredquery).

I created this file.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>WFS Test</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Press<br>
        <input type="button" value="doit" onclick="doit()"/>
        <script language="JavaScript">
            function doit() {

                    var data = '' 
                    + '<wfs:CreateStoredQuery service="WFS" version="2.0.0" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0" xmlns:fes="http://www.opengis.org/fes/2.0" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">'
                    + ' <wfs:StoredQueryDefinition id="SucheFlur">'
                    + '     <wfs:Title>SucheFlur</wfs:Title>'
                    + '     <wfs:Parameter name="gemarkungsname" type="xsd:String"/>'
                    + '     <wfs:QueryExpressionText returnFeatureTypes="KRE_ALKIS:sg_flurstueck_f" language="urn:ogc:def:queryLanguage:OGC-WFS::WFS_QueryExpression" isPrivate="false">'
                    + '         <wfs:Query xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0" xmlns:fes="http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0" xmlns:aixm="http://www.aixm.aero/schema/5.1" typeNames="KRE_ALKIS:sg_flurstueck_f" handle="Q01">'
                    + '             <fes:Filter>'
                    + '                     <ogc:Function name="gemarkungsname">'         
                    + '                         <ogc:PropertyName>gemarkungsname</ogc:PropertyName>'
                    + '                     </ogc:Function>'
                    + '                     <fes:Literal>${gemarkungsname}</fes:Literal>'
                    + '                 </fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>'
                    + '             </fes:Filter>'
                    + '         </wfs:Query>'
                    + '     </wfs:QueryExpressionText>'
                    + ' </wfs:StoredQueryDefinition>'
                    + '</wfs:CreateStoredQuery>';
                    console.log(data);

                $.ajax({type: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://172.16.206.128:8080/geoserver/KRE_ALKIS/wfs?',
                    data: data,
                    contentType: "text/xml",
                    dataType: "text",
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        console.log(xhr.status);
                        console.log(thrownError);
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
</body>
```

When the request is sent, I get an `Error 400 - bad request` and the GeoServer logs these errors.

```
07 Dez 21:05:58 ERROR [geoserver.ows] -
org.geoserver.wfs.WFSException: Request parsing failed
        at org.geoserver.wfs.xml.v2_0.WfsXmlReader.read(WfsXmlReader.java:56)
        at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.parseRequestXML(Dispatcher.java:1606)
        at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:700)
        at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:254)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:998)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:901)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:875)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:865)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1655)
        at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:26)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:69)
        at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:73)
        at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:66)
        at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:41)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:37)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:51)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:81)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:52)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
        at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:142)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:90)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:79)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:46)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.handle(CrossOriginFilter.java:311)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.doFilter(CrossOriginFilter.java:265)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1634)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1340)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1242)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:220)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:503)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:364)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 969; The prefix "ogc" for element "ogc:Function" is not bound.
        at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.geotools.xsd.Parser.parse(Parser.java:235)
        at org.geoserver.wfs.xml.WFSXmlUtils.parseRequest(WFSXmlUtils.java:69)
        at org.geoserver.wfs.xml.v2_0.WfsXmlReader.read(WfsXmlReader.java:52)
        ... 98 more
```

Because I read "Request parsing failed" on the begin of this log I checked the syntax very often. But I find no error.

Why is it not possible to create a `StoredQuery`?

Comment: Check this line `Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 969; The prefix "ogc" for element "ogc:Function" is not bound.`

Comment: You need to add xmlns:ogc.... to the first element